# Finding whether there's any differences in rows grouped by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a dataframe like below

```
id              date                   email        phone     country

john     2020-01-02 10:09:00.11     john@email       123         USA
john     2020-01-02 10:09:00.11     john@email       456         USA
john     2020-01-02 10:09:00.11     john@email       123         USA
tim      2019-01-08 04:06:00.10     tim@email        555         JAP
ben      2018-06-02 08:02:00.00     ben@email        999         MEX
ben      2018-06-02 08:02:00.00     neb@email        999         MEX
john     2017-06-02 08:02:00.00     john@email       456         USA
```

What I'm looking to do is take every row where there is a duplicates between both id and date and see if there are any differences and create a new column indicating so, UNLESS the change is email.

So an example to better explain. There are three rows for john where the date is the same (2020-01-02 10:09:00.11). There is a difference in phone where two are '123' and one is '456'. As a result, in the new column named "diff" the value will be TRUE for each row.

For ben, there are two rows where the date is the same. However, the only difference occurs within the email column, so I want to consider it as there being no difference.

If there happens to only be one row for an id and date combo such as tim or the other entry for John, the output is FALSE.

Below is what the expected output would look like. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The special case regarding emails is really throwing me off.

```
id              date                   email        phone     country      diff

john     2020-01-02 10:09:00.11     john@email       123         USA        True
john     2020-01-02 10:09:00.11     john@email       456         USA        True
john     2020-01-02 10:09:00.11     john@email       123         USA        True
tim      2019-01-08 04:06:00.10     tim@email        555         JAP        False
ben      2018-06-02 08:02:00.00     ben@email        999         MEX        False
ben      2018-06-02 08:02:00.00     neb@email        999         MEX        False
john     2017-06-02 08:02:00.00     john@email       456         USA        False
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

let us use `df.duplicated` with `keep=False` to mark all duplicates.

```
df['diff'] = df.duplicated(subset=['id','date','email'],keep=False)


print(df)

     id                    date       email  phone country   diff
0  john 2020-01-02 10:09:00.110  john@email    123     USA   True
1  john 2020-01-02 10:09:00.110  john@email    456     USA   True
2  john 2020-01-02 10:09:00.110  john@email    123     USA   True
3   tim 2019-01-08 04:06:00.100   tim@email    555     JAP  False
4   ben 2018-06-02 08:02:00.000   ben@email    999     MEX  False
5   ben 2018-06-02 08:02:00.000   neb@email    999     MEX  False
6  john 2017-06-02 08:02:00.000  john@email    456     USA  False
```